# Problems running first shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create my first shell script in bash. I've created the code and I've managed to save the script in my home directory but it wont run. At first I try running it from the home directory with: `./testscript.sh` with "**permission denied**" as a response, i then tried `sudo ./testscript.sh` and then the "**command was not found**".

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash  

mkdir -p/home/filer
touch /home/filer/fil1
touch /home/filer/fil2
touch /home/filer/fil3
tar-zcvf file.tar.gz /home/filer
```

So I've tried creating a script that will create a directory called "filer" in my home directory, using touch to create 3 separate files within the "filer" directory and then creating a tar.archive out of the whole "filer" directory. I think the script is correct, I could just use a hand running the script.

Comment: Did you remember to give it execute permissions?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'm not sure, I thought "**#!**" made it executable?

Comment: `#!<interpreter_path>` just helps the shell to find the interpreter who should execute the script. The script need to have executable permissions first.

Comment: No, that just tells it what to run it with when you do try to execute.  It needs execute permission in the filesystem, which you can add with the `chmod` command.

Comment: Otherwise, you can always try invoking the interpreter directly: `bash testscript.sh`

Comment: Okay guys, I tried running the script with {bash testscript.sh} and I think it worked? This is my result:

tar: Removing leading '\' from member names
/home/hampus/filer/
/home/hampus/filer/fil1
/home/hampus/filer/fil2
/home/hampus/filer/fil3

Seems like we did it?

Comment: Yes, that is the exepected behavior. If you are concerned about the `tar` command warning [see this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59243/tar-removing-leading-from-member-names)

Comment: @Anubis aah brilliant guys, thank's a ton

Comment: @Anubis that link was informative as well, thanks. I would give you a thumbs up, I'm just not able to yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than a couple of typos (`mkdir -p/path` -> `mkdir -p /path`, `tar-zcvf` ... -> `tar -zcvf` ...), you should refer to your home directory using `$HOME` environment variable. `/home/filer` is an absolute directory path, which I am assuming, is not your actual home directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p $HOME/filer
touch $HOME/filer/fil1
touch $HOME/filer/fil2
touch $HOME/filer/fil3
tar -zcvf file.tar.gz $HOME/filer
```

You can execute the script, `./testscript.sh` as `bash testscript.sh` or `./testscript.sh`.

In the second case, the script need to have proper executable permissions. `chmod +x ./testscript.sh` gives it full executable permissions.

Comment: I changed this, i still get "**Command not found**" when i try running it with ./testscript.sh

Comment: the spacing between -p and -zcvf is just a typo on stack, its correct in my script. Thanks for the heads up though. 

As I've understood it, to run this script all that is needed is to enter: "**./**" as I am in the same directory as the testscript.sh file. However once I try running it, **Command not found** is the only response I get.

Comment: Run `bash -xe ./testscript.sh` and tell us the exact output